# android sdk google api full folder path

Tags: android

I would like to know the full folder path under android SDK for android 4.4.2 (api19) of:

-google apis (x86 system image)

-google apis (ARM system image)

-samples for SDK

I'm using eclipse kepler with adt on windows 7

For example my 4.4.2 armeabi-v7a system image is installed under \sdk\system-images\android-19\armeabi-v7a\

I want to do offline installation of those packages and I have the packages zip files for revision 4 and sdk manager is expecting revision 7 as you can see in the image below.I have poor internet connection and I dont want to redownload the latest packages for now.
I tried to put zip archives in sdk tmp folder to let sdk manager install them but it's trying to redownload latest packages instead.

Please if you have them installed in your sdk folder just look at the folder tree and give the full path to me.I already installed my sdk build-tools that way with success.

sorry for my english my first language is french

[image: SDK manager capture]

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps:

1. Copy the files (zip) that you have downloaded to Android SDK's **temp** folder. you could find in Android SDK's folder.
2. In SDK manager,Click any items that you would like to install offline and you have downloded and have copied in step 1.
3. Click **install packages** button.
   package will have been unzip and install on your computer.
   enjoy!